# CouchDB Error log msg

Tags: couchdb

I recently upgraded my server to CouchDB 1.5 and I'm continually seeing this error message in the logs. CouchDB appears to be behaving properly accept for this error.

```
Fri, 14 Feb 2014 19:07:35 GMT] [error] [<0.105.0>] {error_report,<0.31.0>,
                     {<0.105.0>,crash_report,
                      [[{initial_call,
                         {mochiweb_socket_server,init,['Argument__1']}},
                        {pid,<0.105.0>},
                        {registered_name,[]},
                        {error_info,
                         {exit,eaddrinuse,
                          [{gen_server,init_it,6,
                            [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,320}]},
                           {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                            [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},
                        {ancestors,
                         [couch_secondary_services,couch_server_sup,<0.32.0>]},
                        {messages,[]},
                        {links,[<0.94.0>]},
                        {dictionary,[]},
                        {trap_exit,true},
                        {status,running},
                        {heap_size,1598},
                        {stack_size,27},
                        {reductions,593}],
                       []]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EADDRINUSE` means something is already listening on the port that it tried to bind to.

This may be because you have an old copy of CouchDB already running, or it may be because you've chosen a `Port` which is [already in use by another service](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Error_messages#Unavailable_Port).

To resolve the problem, check the `Port` in `/etc/couchdb/couch.ini` (5984 by default) and ensure that no other program is listening on that port, including other running copies of CouchDB.

Comment: I think there is another couch process/instance is attempting to start but I have no idea why.

Comment: I ended up having an orphaned beam.smp